# Onchange populate different dropdown based on value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, dropdown

I'm trying to populate the second dropdown after I select the first option, nothing appears in the second dropdown.

My first select:

```
<select name="inst" class="form-control" required=""  id="inst">
    <option value=0 selected=1>Select...</option>
    <?php
        $sql="SELECT * FROM sapinst";
        $myData=mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'],$sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($myData) > 0){
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($myData))
            {
            echo '<option value="' .$row["nbd"]. '">' .$row["nome"]. '</option>';
            }
        }
        else{echo "No categories were found!";}
        ?>
</select>
```

My second select:

```
<select id= "sub" name="sub" class="form-control"></select>
```

My Script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $("#inst").change(function () {
        //get category value
        var cat_val = $("#inst").val();
        // put your ajax url here to fetch subcategory
        var url = '/ajax.php';
        // call subcategory ajax here
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: {
                cat_val: cat_val
            },
            success: function (data)
            {
                $("#sub").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My Ajax.php file:

```
<?php
    require_once 'edp/configdbedp.php';

    $prod_cat = $_POST['cat_val'];

    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM " . $dbname . ".sappainel WHERE nbd = '$prod_cat'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $msg    = '';
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $msg =. '<option value="' . $row["nome"] . '">' . $row["nome"] . '</option>';
        }
    } else {
        $msg .= "No categories were found!";
    }
    echo $msg;
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

if I try to print some thing in the Ajax php I can't...seems ajax.php won't run.
Am I calling it correctly?

Comment: You have an error on the server side on this line : `$msg =.'<option value="'. $row["nome"] .'">'. $row["nome"] .'</option>';  the `.` should be before `==` so that you can have `$msg .='<option value="'. $row["nome"] .'">'. $row["nome"] .'</option>';`
`

Comment: Thanks Masivuye but second dropdown continue without nothing

Comment: what do u get on the second dropdown

Comment: Nothing....a empty dropdown....no error no warning, nothing

Answer (score 0):

Is your second `ajax` being called properly?
Check the console messages(in developer options, F12) for errors in `ajax` call.

you might want to do this as both `cat_val` are same. It might be giving an error. -

```
data: {
    cat_val: cat_val_local //different variable names here.
},
```

Also `"Select * from $TABLE_NAME(not @dbname)"`
and next remove extra .[dot] here -> `".sappainel WHERE"`

you can also try put `console.log()` in success callback and see if the `success` is returning any elements.

```
success: function (data)
 {
      console.log(data);
      $("#sub").html(data);
 }
```

If nothing is shown then your `php` might be wrong. Add an eror callback too! like this -

```
error: function (e)
 {
      console.log(e);
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved

Diferences on scrip:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                  $("#inst").change(function(){
                      //get category value
                      var cat_val = $("#inst").val();
                      // put your ajax url here to fetch subcategory
                      var url = 'ajax.php';
                      // call subcategory ajax here
                      $.ajax({
                                     type:"POST",
                                     url:url,
                                     data:{
                                         cat_val : cat_val
                                     },

                                     success:function(data)
                                      {
                                          $("#sub").html(data);
                                      }
                                  });
                  });
            </script>
```

On ajax.php

```
<?php

require_once 'edp/configdbedp.php';

$prod_cat = $_POST["cat_val"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$dbname.".sappainel WHERE nbd = '$prod_cat'";
   $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'], $sql);
$msg ='';
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
       $msg .='<option value="'. $row["nome"] .'">'. $row["nome"] .'</option>';
        }
    }
    else{$msg .="No categories were found!";}
    echo ($msg);
    mysqli_close($GLOBALS['con']);


?>
```